# How do I remove every third character from a string in c# If I don't know what character it is?

Tags: c#, string, for-loop

This code should remove every third character and the last character from the String Data variable without the code knowing what characters the String Data contains.

The problem is that this code works well if the length of the String Data is 3 characters, but if it is more, then the characters to be deleted will not be deleted.

If I replace `x == Data.Length` with `x == 3`, then I get a runtime error if I run the code with more than three characters in the String Data variable.

```
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
{
    x++;
    if (x == Data.Length - i) //3
    {
        Data = Data.Remove(i, i - 1);
        Data = Data.Remove(Data.Length - 1);
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two obvious issues with this. First, if you have a 6 char word and remove char 3, then you'll fail to remove char 6 because it's now 5 chars long. You're not accounting for that - it's likely easier to remove in reverse order if you take an imperative approach. Second, you seem to be removing the last character *every time* you remove a character - you only want to do this *once*.

Comment: Just invert the problem.  Instead, start with an empty string and add every 1st and 2nd character.  Logically much simpler, just takes the % operator, and when you use StringBuilder it is far, far more efficient.

Comment: Should "123" give "12" because the third character was removed and the third character was also the last character, or should it give "1" because the third character ("3") was removed and then the last character ("2") was removed?

Comment: This question isn't about using Visual Studio, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's give 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accumulate the required characters into a StringBuilder, then chop off the last one:

```
string datum = "123456789";

var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < datum.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 != 2)
    {
        sb.Append(datum[i]);
    }
}

sb.Length--; // Remove last char
datum = sb.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(datum);
```

Outputs:

```
12457
```

The way a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) works internally is more efficient than repeatedly concatenating to a string.

Comment: You could change the loop in `for (int i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)`, the test `if (i % [N] != 0)` and `sb.Append(input[i-1]);` if it passes the test. So, `[N]` here can be any position (makes it *flexible*) -- Don't know why you're removing the last char. In your output, `8` should included.

Comment: @Jimi The first line of the question says "remove every third character and the last character from the String."

Comment: I read just the title, which omits that info :) I also forgot `=` in `i < input.Length`, which now makes the suggestion *correct*, given that the last char should be removed. Anyway, making the procedure more *dynamic* (so you can evaluate any Nth position) is a no-brainer choice, IMO.

Comment: @Jimi I usually read the body and miss extra info from the title lol. I've asked the OP for clarification regarding the deletion of what may or may not be regarded as the last character.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use lambda `Where` with your logic which will get an `IEnumerable<char>` then passing in string construct method get the result.

```
var result = Data.Where((x,i)=> i%3 != 2 && i != Data.Length -1).ToArray();
Data = new string(result);
```

Comment: As these question tend to lead to lots of suggestions for small optimisations, you could remove the check `&& i != Data.Length -1` and use `new string(result, 0, result.Length - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of [`.Chunk()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0), which lets you split up your string in chunks of (in your scenario) three chars, and of [`.SkipLast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=net-6.0), which lets you skip the last `char` in each chunk. In the end, join all `char`s to create your output string.

```csharp
var output = string.Join(string.Empty, 
    input.Chunk(3).SelectMany(ch => ch.SkipLast(1)));
```

The input

```csharp
var input = "12345678901234567890123456789";
```

will produce

> 1245780134679023568

Both `.Chunk()` and `.SkipLast()` are found in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z8H2Ya).

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
{
    if((i+1)%3==0)
    {
        Data = Data.Remove(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the issue per my comment - `123456789` becomes `1245689` not `124578`

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thanks a lot! It works now, thanks to others for some interesting tactics.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Linq [Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) combined with the [remainder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) operator to gather the chars that are at index 1 or 2, 4 or 5, etc:

```
var Data = "123456789abcdef";
Data = string.Join("", Data.Where((c, i) => (i+1) % 3 > 0));
```

Working .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DlSiiY

Answer (score 0):

Another one using a `List<char>` and going backwards:

```
string input = "1234567890";
List<char> values = new List<char>(input.ToCharArray());
values.RemoveAt(values.Count - 1);
for(int i=(values.Count-1); i>=0;  i--)
{
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        values.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
string output = new string(values.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(" input: " + input);
Console.WriteLine("output: " + output);
```